# Computing $n$th lexicographically smallest permutation of length up to $k$

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, permutations

I wonder how to tackle such problem, to be more specific:

> Given a set and an integer $k$, find the $n$th lexicographically smallest permutation (with repetitions allowed) of the set. We will say that the permutation is valid if its length is *up to* $k$ (inclusive).

Here's an example: $S$ = {a, b, c}, $k$ = 4, $n$ = 15

a aa aaa aaaa aaab aaac aab aaba aabb aabc aac aaca aacb aacc ab

Output should be: "ab" as it's the n-th lexicographically smallest permutation of length up to k of this set.

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. In my book a permutation of a set always has the same length. Perhaps you could give an example?

Comment: And I don't understand what you mean by "permutation (with repetitions allowed) of [a] set". Sets don't have repetitions, and permutations are bijective so you can't create repetitions by permuting something that doesn't already have them.

Comment: But, whatever it is you're looking for, computing permutations and permutation-like objects is a fairly standard problem. So what research did you do before asking here?

Comment: See also Knuth TAoCP 7.2.1.2 Exercise 12.

Answer (score 1):

Your kind of problem reduces to the problem of *enumeration*. For example, suppose that you wanted to know the first letter of the $n$th lexicographically smallest non-empty string of length at most $k$ over the alphabet $S$. You could easily solve that if you could calculate the number of strings of length at most $k$ that start with a given letter.

More generally, the enumeration problem you have to solve in your case is:

> How many strings of length up to $k$ over the alphabet $S$ start with the prefix $w$?

This is not such a hard problem, and I'll let you solve it on your own. I'll also let you figure out how to use the result in order to solve your problem.

Comment: What if I'll say that no two consecutive elements can be the same, will the logic still apply?

Comment: Yes, but the enumeration problem will be slightly more difficult.

Comment: Talking about the harder version, I can't see a way other than keeping increment count and (somehow) generating strings on the fly as you go towards $k$. You don't even know how many strings there will be at all given how big $n$ can be.  I don't want to take too much of your time, could you point me somewhere in the net for the detailed explanation of similar/exact problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any online resources on this matter.