# Compute Permutation Number

Tags: optimization, permutations

Given a permutation on the array of integers 1 through n, I want to find the index of the permutation in a list of all possible permutations of those integers, sorted in lexicographic order.

For example, given the permutation `{1, 3, 2}` with n=3, I want the program to return `1`, because
the array has 6 permutations (`{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}`), and when all the permutations are sorted in lexicographic order, the given permutation is at index 1.

A possible solution is to go through every permutation, but this takes O(n!) time. Is there a way to do this in polynomial time?

This problem seems somewhat related to [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66191/computing-nth-lexicographically-smallest-permutation-of-length-up-to-k), but isn't the same.

If it helps, I am looking to write the code for this problem in C++.

Any potential clarifications are welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74838724/781723

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first observation is that for all $k\in \{1, …, n\}$, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations of size $n$ beginning with $k$.

For a permutation $\sigma = (k_1, …, k_n)$, that means that the rank of $\sigma$ is at least $(k_1-1)\times (n-1)!$.

What you can do to find the exact rank is updating $(k_2, …, k_n)$ by replacing each $k_i$ with $k'_i$ such that:
$$k'_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}k_i&\text{if }k_i<k_1\\k_i-1&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$

The sequence $\sigma'=(k'_2, …, k'_n)$ is then a permutation of $\{1, …, n-1\}$. If $R_n(\sigma)$ represents the rank of $\sigma$ among permutations of size $n$, then:

$$R_n(\sigma) = (k_1-1)\times (n-1)! + R_{n-1}(\sigma')$$
This gives an algorithm in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (assuming the computation of factorials is done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which may not be the case in the general case).

Comment: Thanks! The time complexity could even be lowered to O(nlogn) using prefix sums and a binary index tree.

Comment: I think the [python implementation for `permutation_index`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#permutation_index) uses the same logic as your answer, but the sum of factorials has been factored differently, so that the recursive formula is a bit simpler. (Their code is also O(n²) although it may look O(n) at a glance: the `del` operation inside the loop corresponds to your "updating (k2, ..., kn) by replacing..." and is O(n))

Answer (score 9):

This task is known as ranking permutations.  It can be solved with the factorial number system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506078/781723, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39839119/781723 for further explanations.

More generally, see ranking and unranking (https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions).